# map.fitbounds giving wrong results when bearing is changed

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

**mapbox-gl-js version:** 2.7.0 / all other versions

**browser: Chrome/Safari**

**Steps to Trigger Behavior**
View the jsfiddle (add your own accessToken):
[https://jsfiddle.net/6fk7up9x/16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulsU9.png)

**Expected Behavior**
The markers should be visible at all times(when changing bearing), the map should fit the boundary box depending on the two coordinates that i provided and the provided bearing.

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulsU9.png)

**Actual Behavior**
When changing bearing above 180 or under 100, the markers are not visible anymore.

[Actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykB32.png)

Comment: This looks like a bug report that should be filed on Github Issues, not posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in version 2.8.0. See this [GitHub Pull Request](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/11568)